# How can I display different menu for logged in users using a block theme

Tags: menus, users

I am trying to display a different menu for the logged in users. The problem is that the classic `wp_nav_menu_args` filter does not work for block themes. Or I can't make it work.

Does anybody know how to do it?

Comment: the problem becomes a lot easier to solve if you remove the word menu and replace it with the word block, at that point there are multiple plugins that can hide/show things based on wether the user is logged in, as well as CSS based solutions that rely on the logged in html class WP adds to the body tag and the ability to add classes to blocks